# How to Create GeoJSON from Python List of LineStrings

Tags: python, geojson

I have a python list that looks like this:

```
type(route)
>>>list

print(route)

[{'type': 'LineString',
'coordinates': [[-94.586472, 39.098705],
 [-64.586487, 39.098716],
 [-64.585969, 39.094146],
 [-64.586037, 39.093936],
 [-64.586037, 39.093936],
 [-64.586046, 39.093933]]},
{'type': 'LineString',
'coordinates': [[-94.581459, 39.093506],
 [-64.581451, 39.09351],
 [-64.581444, 39.093506],
 [-64.581459, 39.093433],
 [-64.581726, 39.093418],
 [-64.588631, 39.087582]]},
{'type': 'LineString',
'coordinates': [[-94.584312, 39.042758],
 [-64.584312, 39.042758],
 [-64.583225, 39.099256],
 [-64.584328, 39.09932]]}]
```

How can I convert this into a valid GeoJSON file? I've tried `test = FeatureCollection(features=route)`, but that created an invalid file when I later dumped it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `FeatureCollection` needs each item to be a type of `Feature` which has a [different schema](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.2) than your current routes. The simplest solution is to use list comprehension to map each route into the `Feature` schema.

```
def route_to_feature(idx, route):
    return {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': route,
        'properties': {
            'name': f'Route #{idx}'
        }
    }
```

Which can be used like so.

```
geojson.FeatureCollection([
    route_to_feature(i, route)
    for i, route
    in enumerate(routes)
])
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!